# $k(k^n - (k-1)^n) = k^{n+1}-(k-1)^{n+1}-(k-1)^n$

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, polynomials, factoring

In Feller's Intro to Probability Theory Vol. 1. there is a step I don't know how the author proceded.

You have the full source here

---

[image: here pag. 226]

---

In first place we have (you can ignore the $N^n$):

$$N^n p_k = k^n - (k-1)^n $$

Now we have:

$$E(X) = \sum_{k = 1}^Nkp_k$$ $$ = N^{-n}\sum_{k = 1}^N \{k (k^n - (k-1)^n)\} = N^{-n}\sum_{k = 1}^N \{k^{n+1}-(k-1)^{n+1}-(k-1)^n\}$$

Which is followed by the question:

$$k(k-1)^n \overset{?}{=} (k-1)^{n+1}+(k-1)^n$$

This algebra is the argument for an approximation he later does on the same page number, however I don't believe the last steps he made are correct.

Comment: Have you tried factoring $(k-1)^n$ out?

Comment: I've expanded the expression, but I get a monster sumatory of terms. I'm stuck in just that step.

Comment: No. It is very simple to show $k(k-1)^n = (k-1)^{n+1}+(k-1)^n$.

Comment: How? I just can't see it yet.

Comment: Here's a hint: $1-1=0$, and equivalently $x+1-1=x$

Comment: Hint: it boils down to $(k-1)+1$.

Comment: Oh, thank you. I feel pretty dumb now

Comment: @MartinPrado No worries. It is common to overlook. I do it all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$k(k-1)^n - (k-1)^n = (k-1)(k-1)^n = (k-1)^{n+1}$

and add $(k-1)^n$ to both sides.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try expanding the expression out; try factoring the right-hand side:
$$
(k - 1)^{n+1}
= (k-1)^n(k-1)
$$
so that
$$
(k - 1)^{n + 1} + (k - 1)^{n}
= (k-1)^{n}(k - 1) + (k - 1)^{n} 
= \left[(k - 1) + 1\right](k-1)^{n}
= k(k-1)^{n}.
$$